# iOS app runs fine in Xcode simulator, but is slow and crashes on a device

Tags: ios, performance, swift, uitableview, crash

I have an app that is running fine in the simulator, however when I run it on a device the app runs slow and occasionally crashes. The issue occurs specifically when tapping a tableview cell and transitioning to a new view. When tapping a cell there is a second or two delay, then the new view will be pushed in a slow laggy manner. This is also where it will crash occasionally.

The app was running fine on a device until recently adding some changes to the code, which is where I think the issue lies. I've added the whole viewDidLoad bellow that contains the suspect code (indicated in the code).

One other thing I've noticed is that the CPU usage in the debug navigator hits around 130% while the app runs in the sim at the point where the issue would occur on a device.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // screen size for collection view cell
    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    dimView.alpha = 0
    openingHoursView.alpha = 0

    resDescriptionLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    resDescriptionLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    resDescriptionLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    //add logo to nav bar
    let navBarLogo: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 36))
    navBarLogo.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarLogo

    self.resImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://staging.api.cheapeat.com.au/restaurants/\(self.venueID)/photo") {
        downloadImage(checkedUrl)
    }

    self.resName.text = " " + self.venueName + " "
    self.resAdd.text = " " + self.venueAdd + " "
    self.resPhone.text = "\(self.venuePH)"
    self.resPhoneNumber.text = self.venuePH
    self.resWebText.text = "\(self.venueWeb)"

    ///////////////////// new code starts here //////////////

    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    var attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self.venueInfo,
        attributes: [
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
            NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)

        ])

    self.resDescriptionLabel.attributedText = attributedString

    aboutVenueLabelWidthConstraint.constant = screenWidth - 16

    resDescriptionLabel.edgeInsets.left = 10
    resDescriptionLabel.edgeInsets.top = 10
    resDescriptionLabel.edgeInsets.right = 10
    resDescriptionLabel.edgeInsets.bottom = 10

    resDescriptionLabel.layoutIfNeeded()

    backgroundImageHeightConstraint.constant = resDescriptionLabel.bounds.height + 130

    // set content view height i.e. scrollable area
    // (dynamic height of label + combined height of all other content and contraints)
    contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = resDescriptionLabel.bounds.height + 790

    /////////////////// new code ends here ///////////////

    self.displayMap(self.venueLat, lng: self.venueLng)
    self.getArrayForCollection()
    self.getArrayValues()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        self.getDataForNextTable()
        })

    mon.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Monday")
    tue.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Tuesday")
    wed.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Wednesday")
    thu.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Thursday")
    fri.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Friday")
    sat.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Saturday")
    sun.text = timeFormatting(openingHours, day: "Sunday")
}
```

Comment: try to remove constraints one by one

Comment: Also, make sure that URL is active, I went to the root of it and shows it's not served right now, but it could be that they set it up this way to prevent hacking or something. Also, I'm not sure what your function "        downloadImage(checkedUrl)" does, it would be helpful to see  what this function does to determine if this is the culprit

Comment: Use Xcode tool Instruments called "Time Profiler" to detect your problem place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit, turns out it wasn't in the code after all. I had set some background images in a scrollView that were at huge resolutions (5000x5000). They were absolutely chewing up the memory (was hitting around 400mb in the debugger). I resized the images, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I was using an 8000 x 8000 image as an UIButton Background Image. replacing it with a 300 x 300 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the lag & crash is coming from that synchronous looking         `downloadImage(checkedUrl)` call, but only [profiling via Xcode Instruments will tell you for certain](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode).

Not only do you depend on a potentially slow network to fetch the image *on your main thread*, but you don't know how big that image is going to be (if it's a high resolution image, and you already have many other high-rez UIImages loaded in other cells, you're likely to crash out of an app on your low memory device).

This isn't going to be a trivial fix where I can just type code in to solve it for you, but I recommend doing a few changes:

1)

Use an image cache that downloads the pictures asynchronously

e.g. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

2)

Display smaller (and less memory intensive) thumbnails in your table view and not full size images.

e.g. [maybe via this technique](http://beageek.biz/how-to-create-thumbnail-uiimage-xcode-ios/)